# Existence of solution for an equation including polynomial and trinogometric sum

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Prove that the following equation has at least a solution in $[-\pi, \pi]$ :

$$
x^5+\sum^{n}_{k=1}(a_k\cos kx+b_k\sin kx)=0
$$

I think the existence of the solution on $[-\pi, \pi]$ strongly depends on the parameter $a_k, b_k$ but I can't go any far.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: What is $n$ in your equation?

Comment: $n$ is arbitrary integer, it can vary

Answer (score 2):

First, observe that 
$$
\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi \cos kx \,\mathrm{d}x=\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi \sin kx \,\mathrm{d}x=0
$$
for any positive integer $k$. Using the integral's linearity, we get
$$
\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi \left( x^5+\sum^{n}_{k=1}(a_k\cos kx+b_k\sin kx)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
=\sum^{n}_{k=1}\left(\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi a_k\cos kx\,\mathrm{d}x+\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi b_k\sin kx\,\mathrm{d}x
\right)=0,
$$

and since the equation's left hand side is continuous, there has to be at least one solution in $[-\pi,\pi]$.